# Javascript canvas

Tags: javascript, canvas

I have been looking for a way to make a system in which the camera/viewport follows the player as it moves. As you can see on the fiddle, the map is much larger that the canvas and i wanted to make so that the player is allways on the center unless close to the edges.

The player doesnt move yet. I think i need to pass some variables to x and y positions.

Also, if you know any good tutorial about this, i would be very appreciated.

please help...

thanks in advance.

my js code:

```
var canvas = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
        if (canvas.getContext) {
            var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

            var width = 800;
            var height = 700;

            var level = [];
            var level_1 = [
                "bbggggggbbgggggggggggggggggg",
                "gbggggggbbgggbbbbbbggggggggg",
                "gbggggggbbgggbgggggggggggggg",
                "gbbbbbbbbbbbbbgggggggggggggg",
                "ggggggggggbggggggggggggggggg",
                "ggggggggggbggggggggggggggggg",
        "ggggggggggbggggggggggggggggg",
                "ggggggggggbggggggggggggggggg",
        "ggggggggggbggggggggggggggggg",
                "ggggggggggbggggggggggggggggg",
        "ggggggggggbggggggggggggggggg",
                "ggggggggggbggggggggggggggggg"
            ];


            var Ground = function(x, y, label) {
                this.x = x;
                this.y = y;
                this.label = label;

        this.draw = function() {
            if(this.label == "g") {
            ctx.fillStyle = 'rgb(0,255,0)';
            ctx.fillRect(this.x, this.y, 15, 15);
          }
          if(this.label == "b") {
            ctx.fillStyle = 'rgb(0,0,255)';
            ctx.fillRect(this.x, this.y, 15, 15);
          }
        }
      }

      var Player = function(x, y) {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
        this.size = 10;

        this.draw = function() {
            ctx.fillStyle = 'rgb(0,0,0)';
          ctx.fillRect(this.x, this.y, this.size, this.size);
        }

        this.move = function() {
         // code for player to move
        }
      }

            var makeLevel = function() {
                for(var i = 0; i < level_1.length; i++) {
                    for(var j = 0; j < level_1[i].length; j++) {
                        switch(level_1[i][j]) {
                            case "g" :
                                level.push(new Ground(j*15, i*15, "g"));
                                break;
              case "b" :
                                level.push(new Ground(j*15, i*15, "b"));
                                break;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

            makeLevel();

      var player = new Player(5,20);

            function draw() {
                ctx.clearRect(0,0,800,700);

        for(var i=0; i<level.length; i++) {
                    level[i].draw();
                }

        player.draw();

                window.requestAnimationFrame(draw);
            }

            draw();
         }
```

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/eskimopest/5p5nqow8/1/)

Answer (score 0):

Your camera/viewport is your canvas size. You need to keep in mind each object will have two different positions.

1. Map position
2. Canvas position (if they are in the view port or not)(no point in calculating this if they are not in the view port)

In a 2D game where the player is always in the center, your "map" is what moves. What you need to do before you render your scene is the following:

1. Update any dynamic objects map positions
2. Update your player map position
3. Using the dimensions of your canvas define the surface area (aka the min and max boundaries... should be 4 corners of your canvas) on the map corresponding to your player's position
4. Get all objects (static / dynamic) in that surface area (the objects that are in the boundaries of the viewport)
5. Convert their map positions to the canvas position (using your player's map position and player's canvas position and canvas dimensions).
6. Once you have all the canvas positions of the the objects, render the scene.

If you have any questions, feel free to leave a comment. I might not have been clear on certain parts.